# Encoding issue with Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, error, character-encoding, special-character

I am using symbols like these in My Magento pages:

✓ ☳ ▣

For some reason now the symbols are being changed by Magento to these weird characters:

ÃÂÃÂ£ÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂ
Ã¢ÂÂ

I have read other threads and they indicate it's an encoding issue. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `UTF-8` encoding to your config.

Comment: Encoding was right in Magento and database.